# Action before Switch changes its state in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, switch-statement

I need to show "You are sure?" dialog when user want to change toggle position to off.

I create a check function and assigned a setOnClickListener function to the switch

```
private fun checkSwitchStatus() {
        if (!reminderSwitch.isChecked) {
            reminderSwitch.isChecked = true
            showCancelPopup()
        } else {
            reminderSwitch.isChecked = true
        }
    }
```

Now the switch does not turn off visually, but the setOnCheckedChangeListener function is still processed and *some action* happens..

```
 override fun onCheckedChanged(buttonView: CompoundButton?, isChecked: Boolean) {
        if (!isChecked) {
            showCancelPopup()
        } else {
            //*some action*
        }
    }
```

How to do some action before switch change its state, and be able to undo state change?

Comment: What do you mean by undo state change? What action are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I need to ask the user whether he wants to turn off the switch before the switch starts to change its state, and do not change the state if the user answered "do not change" in the dialog.
Right now I just return the switch to the "on" state after turning off, but this is not correct since triggered onCheckedChanged
@Haroon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `setClickable(false)` on your Switch, then listen for the `onClick` event within the Switch's parent and toggle it programmatically. The switch will still appear to be enabled but the swipe animation won't happen and its state won't change.

Since you want to reaffirm the user's choice, show a dialog in `onClick` and have your switch's state be dependent on whether a 'yes' was tapped in on the dialog.

```
// if yes was tapped on the Dialog
        switchInternet.setChecked(true);           
    } else {
        switchInternet.setChecked(false);    
    }
```

Comment: This solution works. I was afraid that the switching animation would be lost, but visually the switching looks exactly the same. thank!